# JavaFX setting a Comparator for theTableColumn results in compiler error

Tags: javafx

I am trying to set a Comparator for a TableColumn and I get an incompatible type compiler error.

Any idea?
Thanks

import java.util.Comparator;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;

```
public class MyTableColumn {

    Comparator<String> columnComparator = (String v1, String v2) -> {
        return v1.toLowerCase().compareTo(v2.toLowerCase());
    };
    public static void main(String[] args){
        TableColumn taCol = new TableColumn();
        taCol.setComparator(columnComparator);
    }

}
```

Comment: Not sure you can name a class the same as a class that’s imported...

Comment: @James_D: Good point. I renamed the class but the compiler error persists.

Comment: You also should not use raw types.

Comment: @James_D: I apologize, I don't follow your last comment, would it be possible to elaborate further? Thanks

Comment: You’re using a raw type: `TableColumn`. You should specify the type parameters for it.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the compiler error. Now, I hope, the comparator work properly.